# Pagination on Laravel DB tables method

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to use native pagination on the `DB::table()->get()` method? Now, I have 3000+ records in a specific table, and I'd like to trigger pagination of 1000 records at a time.

Here is the method that I have:

```
public function refresh()
{
    $records = DB::table('employees')->get();

    foreach ($records as $record)
    {
        $record = $this->getRecord($record);
        $record->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $record->save();
    }

    return $record;
}
```

Thanks all!

Update:

Thanks to the help from Arif, I was able to paginate through the table as needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! you can do that using paginate function   `$records = DB::table('employees')->paginate(1000);` more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#introduction)

Comment: Hi @Arif, Sorry for the late reply, this worked great! Would you be able to upvote my post?

Answer (score 0):

put your query into a collection function

```
eg. $record

return collection($record)->paginate(10);
```